# How to force subclass to implement some methods in java?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have the `Screen` interface in libgdx framework.

I create a subclass called `BaseLayout`, where I initialize some fields.

Now for every actual screen e.g. MenuScreen I extend this `BaseLayout` class.

I want to force these classes e.g. MenuScreen to implement two methods 
`void initData()`, and `void addButtonsToScreen()`. **How to do this?**

I call these methods in the `show` method only implemented in the base class `BaseLayout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to force these classes e.g. MenuScreen to implement two methods void initData(), and void addButtonsToScreen(). How to do this?

Make `BaseLayout` an `abtract class` and make `initData()` and `addButtonsToScreen()` abstract methods.

**Example**

```
public abstract class BaseLayout extends Screen
{
     public void initData();
     public void addButtonsToScreen();
}
```

Then you simply make subclasses extend and implement those methods..

```
public class ConcreteLayout extends BaseLayout
{
     public void initData()
     {
         // Some code here.
     }

     public void addButtonsToScreen()
     {
         // Some code here.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please declare those methods as [abstract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Ex :

An `abstract method` is a method that is declared without an implementation (without braces, and followed by a semicolon), like this:

```
abstract void moveTo(double deltaX, double deltaY);
```

Comment: but my BaseLayout class is not abstract

Comment: Why can't you *make* it `abtract`?

Comment: sorry my mistake, i can make it

Comment: @user494461 and remember `Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this:

1- Declare your `Baselayout` Class as an `abstract` class and declare the `methods` that you want to force child `classes` to implement as `abstract` too.

2-Other way could be to define an interface in your `BaseLayout` `Class` that defines the two methods , then implement that `Interface` in your `Child` class.